# psql - Check if json value has specific property

Tags: json, postgresql

I'm trying to delete rows from a table depending on a specific value on a `details` column which is of `json` type.

The column is expected to have a `json` value like this one:

```json
{
  "tax": 0, 
  "note": "", 
  "items": [
     {
       "price": "100", 
       "quantity": "1", 
       "description": "Test"
     }
  ]
}
```

The objects inside `items` could have a `name` entry or not. I'd like to delete those that don't have that entry.

**NOTE: All objects inside items have the same entries so all of them will have or will not have the `name` entry**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a JSON path expression.

```
delete from the_table
where details::jsonb @@ '$.items[*].name <> ""'
```

This checks if there is at least one array element where the name is not empty. Note that this wouldn't delete rows with an array element having `"name": ""`

---

As you didn't use the recommended `jsonb` type (which is the one that supports all the nifty JSON path operators), you need to cast the column to `jsonb`.